# How to consolidate 2 functions into a single one (Use one function to target multiple classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions doing the same thing, just targeting two different classes on my page. Is there a way to consolidate these two into a single function?

```
$(document).on("click", ".class1", function(event) {
      const $this = $(this);
      if ($this.find($(event.target).closest("a")[0]).length === 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $this.find("a")[0].click();
      }
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".class2", function(event) {
      const $this = $(this);
      if ($this.find($(event.target).closest("a")[0]).length === 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $this.find("a")[0].click();
      }
  });
```

I have a lot of cards on the page that have the class1 and class2 name, I know I can give them each an extra class something like .clickable and add it to every single card on the page, but I was wondering if there's an easier way to just have this function target 2 classes at once.

Comment: Pull out the function and give it a name. Use that function as the argument to `on`'s function parameter. (Or just extend the selector.)

Comment: `".class1,.class2"` is the way to do this, and [trivial to confirm that part](https://jsfiddle.net/km6vsqxy/) if that's not working for you, there must be some other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them together like this

to activate the anchor link on the first matching `<a>` element

```js
$(document).on("click", ".class1, .class2", function(event) {
  if ($(this).find($(event.target).closest("a")[0]).length === 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).find("a")[0].click();
      }
     // $(event.target).find("a").eq(0)[0]?.click();
});
```

```css
.padd {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#gohere{
margin-top:500px;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1 padd'>
  <a href='#gohere' onclick='console.log("CLICKED1")'>the link</a><br>
  <a href='#' onclick='console.log("this should not fire....")'>a second link</a>
</div>

<div class='class2 padd'>
  <a href='#' onclick='console.log("CLICKED2")'>the link</a>
</div>


<div class='class2 padd'>
  no link here
</div>


<div id='gohere'>Anchor link text....</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm. I updated my answer to prove the concept, and made your script a lot lighter along the way. Check it out.

Comment: @Kinglish needs to be `.find("a")[0].click()` as jquery click won't fire the default click handler on anchors (like you had in original, so probably not why OP can't get this to work)

Comment: @freedomn-m -- thank you. I missed that completely - answer updated.

Comment: 1) `.eq(0)` is not the same as `[0]` - [0] converts to a DOM element and calls DOM click. (I see you spotted this) 2) should be `$(this).find(...` as the `event.target` is the `a` (the thing being clicked rather than the `.click1,.click2` handler assignment) - so won't find a child `a`

Comment: @freedomn-m -- .eq(0) was meant to only find the first matching element, which I then appended [0] to access the actual DOM element. The ? added in meant the script would fail silently if there was no such element. If there is an A tag inside of an A tag, the code has much larger issues. Still, I went with your recommendation and left the one liner in there as a commented out reference